Flutter - SfCartesianChart package i want labels next to bars
In flutter i m using SfCartesianChart package to crate bar chart, but i want to get the lables of bars next to each bar, not inside or before.
below is my UI design what i want

and below is my code
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:attendanceapp/utils/theme/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:attendanceapp/utils/widgets/custom_text_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class CustomLeavebalanceCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final double totalLeaves;
  final double totalAbsentees;
  final double totalPresent;
  final double totalOff;

  const CustomLeavebalanceCard({
    super.key,
    required this.totalLeaves,
    required this.totalAbsentees,
    required this.totalPresent,
    required this.totalOff,
  });

  @override
  State<CustomLeavebalanceCard> createState() => _CustomLeavebalanceCardState();
}

class _CustomLeavebalanceCardState extends State<CustomLeavebalanceCard> {
  // Function to return a list of map data with unique colors
  List<_LeaveData> getBarChartData() {
    return [
      _LeaveData('Leaves', widget.totalLeaves, AppColors.leaveColor),
      _LeaveData('Absentees', widget.totalAbsentees, AppColors.absentColor),
      _LeaveData('Present', widget.totalPresent, AppColors.presentColor),
      _LeaveData('Off', widget.totalOff, AppColors.oFFColor),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaH = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;
    final mediaW = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
    List<_LeaveData> barData = getBarChartData(); // Fetch the chart data

    return Column(
      children: [
        customTextWidget(
            text: "Display Balance Leave",
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        OverflowBar(
          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: mediaH * 0.3,
              width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.6,
              child: SfCartesianChart(
                
                
                primaryXAxis: const CategoryAxis(
                  labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.inside,
                ),
                primaryYAxis: const NumericAxis(
                  labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.inside,
                ),
                // Chart title
                // title: const ChartTitle(text: 'Display Balance Leave'),
                // Enable tooltip
                tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
                series: <CartesianSeries<dynamic, dynamic>>[
                  BarSeries<dynamic, String>(
                    dataSource: barData,
                    xValueMapper: (dynamic data, _) => data.label,
                    yValueMapper: (dynamic data, _) => data.value,
                    pointColorMapper: (dynamic data, _) =>
                        data.color, // Unique color for each bar
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    isTrackVisible: true, // Show background track
                    width: 0.6,
                    //     MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.4, // Set the bar width
                    dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: mediaH * 0.3,
              width: mediaW * 0.4,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  customTextWidget(
                      text: "Policy of Attendance:",
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  customTextWidget(
                    text:
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// Model for leave data
class _LeaveData {
  final String label;
  final double value;
  final Color color; // Add color field

  _LeaveData(this.label, this.value, this.color);
}


I tried with documentation and labels property but didnt find the solution yet. Like initially it was at before the bars which is outside property but it was before the bars, then i applied inside property. But did not getting what i want.

Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

any other easy and handy package?

There are many charting and graphing packages in the pub.  The most commonly used is fl_chart.

Thanks, i first tried fl_chart but its not providing horizontal bar chat as I want.
